# conventional matrix notation for distance interval

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mathematical-physics, mathematics

Why matrix notation for distance interval is represented by this?

$$g_{\mu \nu}\Delta  X^{\mu}\Delta X^{\nu}=(\Delta X)^Tg (\Delta X)=\Delta  X^{\mu}\Delta X^{\nu}g_{\mu \nu}$$

Could you explain this, please?

Why one of the $\Delta X$ come in the other side of $g$ and being transposed?

Why not $g(\Delta X)^2$ or $(\Delta X)g(\Delta X)$?

Why if $g$ be in the right-hand side or in the left-hand side the matrix representation is the same?

Comment: See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation for details. It would be helpful to know what exactly in that expression is confusing you and what you do understand - is it the index placement, the transpose, something else?

Comment: @jacob1729, Thank you for your comment. I don't have a problem with Einstein notation apparently. My question is related to the matrix notation. I've edited.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276945/index-notation-matrix-calculation-intro-to-relativity?rq=1 although the answers there don't seem to deal explicitly with the transpose notation.

Comment: The $(\Delta X)^T$ is a row vector, $g$ a matrix and ($\Delta X)$ a column vector. When you execute those matrix/vector products you get a number, the distance. This is the same as contracting the tensors. Remember that a matrix is a second rank tensor and a vector a first rank tensor.

Comment: @WarreG, Thanks, then by your explanation, it should be the same as $g(\Delta X)^T(\Delta X)$. right?

Comment: No, because you can't multiply a matrix with a row. It must be in the order you wrote it originally.

Comment: @Schok if you are confused by this, write out the dimensions and see that it will only work in one way.